# How to Use CustomSliding Drawer like Statusbar Notification in android App

Tags: android

am new to android apps am making an app Which has NFc technology,here i want to make a Notification bar like default OS statusbar Notification.
i made it custom now i want it to be call/display in all Screen while end user pull it from top to bottom within the app.

this is my custom Sliding drawer class and am using it in Main.xml file

```
<com.abc.xyx.customnotification.CustomDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.abc.xyx.app"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    my:direction="topToBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    my:handle="@+id/handle"
    my:content="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@id/content"
        layout="@layout/slider"/>
    <ImageView

        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:src="@drawable/tooltiparea" />
</com.abc.xyx.customnotification.CustomDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should google it up, there are quite a few samples with good explanation, like these:

- [Android SlidingDrawer with Custom View](https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/) or
- [Example to implement
  SlidingDrawer in XML](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/04/example-to-implement-slidingdrawer-in.html) or
- [Widget: SlidingDrawer top to bottom](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/)

Comment: hey i made it custom,now what i want exactly means i need to display in all activities whether user can see him Notification anywhere.

Comment: you should show some code snippets (classes, layouts), your effort on how are you trying to solve this issue, and the logcat output in case you have any exceptions. StackOverflow helps you solving problems, won't make the job instead of / for you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use oops for that

first make a BaseActivity which extends android.app.Activity. Now this will be the parent Activity for all of your app's Activities where you want to display status bar. Define all the function related to custom status bar in that and  a parent layout for holding views related to child Ativity

xml layout for BaseActivity will be like this

```
    <com.abc.xyx.customnotification.CustomDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.abc.xyx.app"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    my:direction="topToBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    my:handle="@+id/handle"
    my:content="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@id/content"
        layout="@layout/slider"/>
    <ImageView

        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:src="@drawable/tooltiparea" />
</com.abc.xyx.customnotification.CustomDrawer>


<RelativeLayout >
this layout is used for holding child Activities views
</RelativeLayout>
```

generate accesser method to access the slidingdrawer and parentLayout.

now your activities in which you want to add customSlidingBar should extends from BaseActivity in this way you only have to code once for sliding drawer implemation

hope it helps