# Will touch get detected while a View is in invisible state?

Tags: android

I am using a CustomSlider in my app, and I have set it to be invisible.

When the user drags it or touches it (from top to bottom), my application needs to make the slider visible.  Is this possible?  How would I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The touch event will be detected on the visible `View`s of your activity. While a `View` instance is `hidden / invisible`, you cannot interact with it.

You need a motion handler on the parent view / visible view to determine whether you need to show the slider (in case the motion is vertical) or not.

Comment: yeah i tried with invisible mode its not detecting.thanks for ur comment.

Comment: you're welcome, I hope though the answer will guide you to the right direction.

Comment: ofcourse and am trying to implement the above functionality.image view  not taking touch event can u know y.for reference see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578660/how-to-use-customsliding-drawer-like-statusbar-notification-in-android-app/10578779#comment13698541_10578779

Comment: you can attach both `OnTouchListener` and `OnClickListener` to an image, but it won't respond to any events unless it is in `visible` state. On the link you've provided you have the `ImageView` invisible, so there's no way it can detect user interaction / respond.

Comment: thanks rekaszeru,actually i dont know there is some Listener for sliding drawer like  **OnDrawerOpenListener** and OnDrawerCloseListener.instaed of TouchListemer i used those Listener finally i implmented what i want exactly.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to do this with an ImageView and still get touch events.  The solution was to setAlpha(0.0f) to hide the image and still get events.